# Terrible write speeds with Z77 Intel 510 RAID 0

Tags: ssd, performance, raid, speed, intel-rst

I just bought an Asus P8Z77-V Pro board today, connected my old Intel 510's in RAID 0 mode on the Intel controller and installed Windows 7. I'm gettings read speeds of around 900mb/s, but the writes are terrible at around 30mb/s in CrystalDiskMark.

Could this be a TRIM issue? The drives were used on an LSI controller without TRIM support before, but i never really investigated the write speed until now. I have installed the Intel Rapid Storage software 11.6, and from what i understand 11.2+ should have TRIM support even in RAID 0 mode.

Where do i continue looking? Which device in the device manager should show an Intel driver? Anything related to disks or controllers says Microsoft and 2006 which seems kind of fishy.

Here are my numbers:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CrystalDiskMark 3.0.2 x64 (C) 2007-2012 hiyohiyo
                           Crystal Dew World : http://crystalmark.info/
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
* MB/s = 1,000,000 byte/s [SATA/300 = 300,000,000 byte/s]

       Sequential Read :   867.309 MB/s
      Sequential Write :    30.810 MB/s
     Random Read 512KB :   443.085 MB/s
    Random Write 512KB :    15.921 MB/s
Random Read 4KB (QD=1) :    19.925 MB/s [  4864.6 IOPS]
Random Write 4KB (QD=1) :     5.200 MB/s [  1269.6 IOPS]
Random Read 4KB (QD=32) :   148.987 MB/s [ 36373.9 IOPS]
Random Write 4KB (QD=32) :     6.997 MB/s [  1708.3 IOPS]

Test : 1000 MB [C: 35.7% (166.1/465.8 GB)] (x3)
Date : 2012/11/25 22:37:33
OS : Windows 7 Ultimate Edition SP1 [6.1 Build 7601] (x64)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used the "Intel SSD Optimizer" in the SSD toolkit, it took five seconds, and writes are  now between 400 to 600mb/s. I realize this can be set on a schedule, which i will, but why isnt this done automatically if its so fast, and as the toolbox states "doesnt cause any wear"?

Here are the new numbers for reference:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CrystalDiskMark 3.0.2 x64 (C) 2007-2012 hiyohiyo
                           Crystal Dew World : http://crystalmark.info/
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
* MB/s = 1,000,000 byte/s [SATA/300 = 300,000,000 byte/s]

       Sequential Read :   933.728 MB/s
      Sequential Write :   609.283 MB/s
     Random Read 512KB :   471.231 MB/s
    Random Write 512KB :   454.620 MB/s
 Random Read 4KB (QD=1) :    21.569 MB/s [  5266.0 IOPS]
 Random Write 4KB (QD=1) :    90.193 MB/s [ 22019.8 IOPS]
  Random Read 4KB (QD=32) :   159.978 MB/s [ 39057.1 IOPS]
 Random Write 4KB (QD=32) :    92.492 MB/s [ 22581.0 IOPS]

Test : 1000 MB [C: 35.9% (167.3/465.8 GB)] (x3)
Date : 2012/11/25 22:55:43
OS : Windows 7 Ultimate Edition SP1 [6.1 Build 7601] (x64)
```